# PHP own functions autocomplete from included files in Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: php, autocomplete, dreamweaver, flash-cs5, code-hinting

I'm using Dreamweaver CS5. I know that code hinting works in Dreamweaver with own functions/classes, but only if the functions file is included one level from main script.

Here an example:

> main_script.php
>
> > include(my_functions.php)

this work and all functions which included in `my_functions.php` will hint when I'm editing the main_script.php (strg + space).

Other example:

> main_script.php (own functions not available)
>
> > include(global_config.php) (own functions available)
> >
> > > include(my_functions.php) (own functions available)

Do you know if there is some trick or fix in other versions of Dreamweaver? If code hinting would work with several included levels that would make work much easier.

I've searched this site and several others but didn't find anybody with nearly the same problem, maybe somebody here can help.

Comment: If you don't mind switching IDEs, NetBeans will offer auto-complete for all files in a project (and external ones too if you configure an include in the editor). I should think Eclipse and PHPStorm will also do this.

Comment: Why are you using Dreamweaver as an IDE?  It's not well-suited to the job, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for the Editors you suggest me. I just tried out the PHPStorm and this Support codeHinting with several included files in a Project automaticly.

I just found out that Dreamweaver CS5 also Support this, in a bit other way here is a good tutorial Video for this: 
http://tv.adobe.com/de/watch/lerne-dreamweaver-cs5/code-hinting-und-phphilfestellungen/

You can config a custome code hinting under "Site" => "SiteSpecific CodeHints"

Better then nothing ;)

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works in dreamweaver but you could try adding a phpdoc eg:

```
include('global_config.php');

/* @var $functions Functions */

$functions = new Functions();
```

This assumes your functions are wrapped in a class

Comment: i do not have experience in that, how that will work?
My Functions are include in 1 file like this:

include(func_upload_file.php); # func_upload_file()
include(func_delete_file.php); # func_delete_file()

This file is included in my mainconfig_glob.php script